# How to dynamically set headers in Retrofit (Android)

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using an API that uses an authorization scheme that requires a special "X-Authorization" header to be set to authenticate the request. For example, this Retrofit setup works perfectly for the user whose auth token is `abc123`:

```
@Headers("X-Authorization: abc123")
@GET("/posts")
Observable<List<Post>> get_posts();
```

I cache the user's X-Authorization token, so I have access to that, however, I can't just drop it in the @Headers declaration.

```
@Headers("X-Authorization: " + token)
@GET("/posts")
Observable<List<Post>> get_posts();
```

I get a compile error here: `Error:(41, 34) error: element value must be a constant expression`

Any ideas on how I could get around this?

Comment: Yeah, this part [`(@Headers("X-Authorization: " + token)`] is evaluated at compile time IIRC. So it won't set the token dynamically

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Since Retrofit 2.0 you have two options

---

1) Using OkHttp 2.2+ use [Interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Interceptor.kt)

At the Http level, you have more control over the request, so you could do things like applying headers only to a specific request made to a specific endpoint, and so on.

```
public class MyOkHttpInterceptor implements Interceptor {

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request originalRequest = chain.request();
    if (!"/posts".contains(originalRequest.url()) ) {
        return chain.proceed(originalRequest);
    }

    String token = // get token logic 

    Request newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
        .header("X-Authorization", token)
        .build();

    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
}

[...]

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new MyOkHttpInterceptor());
OkClient okClient = new OkClient(okHttpClient);
YourApi api = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(url)
            .setClient(okClient)
            .build()
            .create(YourApi.class);
```

---

***Edit***: 
Adding [@JakeWarthon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132047/jake-wharton) comment as another option as is also valid.

2) Put [@Header](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Header.html) on a method parameter and pass it as a value when invoking.

*From the [docs](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Header.html):*

```
// Replaces the header with the the value of its target.
@GET("/")
void foo(@Header("Accept-Language") String lang, Callback<Response> cb);
```

Header parameters may be null which will omit them from the request. Passing a List or array will result in a header for each non-null item.

Note: Headers do not overwrite each other. All headers with the same name will be included in the request.

---

***EDIT:*** This option should not be considered as Retrofit 2.* dropped support for interceptors.

<strike>3) User retrofit RequestInterceptor</strike>

From the docs: 
**Intercept every request before it is executed in order to add additional data.**

You could do something like

```
public class MyRetrofitInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

@Override
public void intercept(RequestFacade req) {
    String token = // get token logic 
    if (token != null) {
        req.addHeader("X-Authorization", token);
    }
}

[...]

YourApi api = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(url)
            .setRequestInterceptor(new MyRetrofitInterceptor())
            .build()
            .create(YourApi.class);
```

The "problem" with this approach is that the interceptor will get executed on all the endpoints, as it's set at the RestAdapter level, and not per endpoint. Also, the `RequestFacade` doesn't expose much information about the request, so no chance to add much logic around it.

Comment: I didn't knew @Header can be included as parameter. I was struggling with interceptors because my Apiclient class  is a singleton and adding interceptors requires me to break singleton pattern. Glad I found this answer.

Comment: For anyone setting a "standard" header in an interceptor, but needing to override it for just a few requests: the `@Header` directive will _not_ work, as the interceptor executes later and will overwrite it. I ended up putting a conditional in my interceptor, and setting the header based on `chain.request().url`.

Answer (score 32):

Passing header in parameter would be helpful. Look to the following code;

```
 @GET("/posts")
Observable<JsonElement> getDataFromService(
        @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,
        @QueryMap HashMap<String, Object> queryParams
);

        hashMap1.put("Authorization", token);
    return ApiService.getAPI_test().getDataFromService(hashMap1, url, hashMap)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

Update:

More better would be

```
 @GET("/posts")
Observable<JsonElement> getDataFromService(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String = "Bearer " + PreferenceUtils.getToken(),
        @QueryMap HashMap<String, Object> queryParams
);
```

Answer (score 21):

**Dynamic Header In Retrofit 2**

I have struggled too much to add Dynamic Header In Retrofit 2.

I have gone through so many blogs and StackOver flow. Everyone has shown example with Interceptor.

And it’s not a wise thing ,just for one API call we need to do that much work.

You just have to add **@HeaderMap** as argument of fun. I have done in very simple way :-

**In Kotlin**

```
    val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
    headers["KEY_AUTHORIZATION"] = "paste AUTHORIZATION value here"
    headers["KEY_TOKEN"] = "paste TOKEN value here"

    val jsonObject= JsonObject()

I am passing here header and other data also
Calling of fun:-

postEvent(headers,jsonObject)

API Declaration 

    @POST("/v1/post_data")
    fun postEvent(@HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>, @Body jsonObject: JsonObject): Call<JsonObject>

API Declaration with RxAndroid

    @POST("/v1/post_data")
    fun postEvent(@HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>, @Body jsonObject: JsonObject): Single<JsonObject>
```

2nd argument here i have JsonObject. You can replace with anything whatever you need to pass or you can remove it also.

**In Java**

```
 HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("KEY_AUTHORIZATION","paste AUTHORIZATION value here");
    headers.put("KEY_TOKEN", "paste TOKEN value here");

    JsonObject jsonObject= new JsonObject();

I am passing here header and other data also

Calling of fun:-
postEvent(headers,jsonObject);

    API Declaration 
    @POST("/v1/post_data")
    Call<JsonObject> postEvent(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers, @Body JsonObject jsonObject);

API Declaration with RxAndroid

    @POST("/v1/post_data")
    Single<JsonObject> postEvent(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers, @Body JsonObject jsonObject);
```

2nd argument here i have JsonObject. You can replace with anything whatever you need to pass or you can remove it also.

Answer (score 7):

A request Header can be updated dynamically using the @Header annotation. A corresponding parameter must be provided to the @Header. If the value is null, the header will be omitted. Otherwise, toString will be called on the value, and the result used.

```
@GET("user")
Call<User> getUser(@Header("Authorization") String authorization)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the last part of this answer
[How to dynamically set headers in Retrofit (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29885004/787399)
did not work for me (halfway of the project), I improved it:-

```
public class MyRetrofitInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
// volatile variable
public static String token = null; //change at start of app
@Override
public void intercept(RequestFacade req) {
    // change token from outside the class.
    if (token != null) {
        req.addHeader("X-Authorization", token);
    }
}
```

It worked as soon as the token was updated from the response from the server API.

I think it worked as the string variable 'token' was used as the reference to its value, in global terms (being public static).