# Retrofit does not send header

Tags: php, android, header, retrofit

I'm currently working on an Android app and I have a problem, I'm trying to send a header in my request with retrofit but when I check on my server with PHP it looks like the header does not even exists.
Here is my code:
**Android**

```
@Headers("SECRET_KEY: QWERTZUIOP")
@GET("{TableName}/")
Call<List<Data>> cl_getAllFromTable(@Path("TableName") String TableName);
```

**PHP Server**

```
$secret_key = $_SERVER['HTTP_SECRET_KEY'];
```

I'd be glad if someone could help. Thanks in advance.
Teasel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963394/how-to-use-interceptor-to-add-headers-in-retrofit-2-0 You have to intercept and add the header manually.

Comment: I need to send the header from my app, is that possible ? Can you tell me more please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884967/how-to-dynamically-set-headers-in-retrofit-android  The accepted answer gives an explanation and several options!

Comment: Why is "SECRET_KEY" and "HTTP_SECRET_KEY" different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Define the interceptor, add authentication headers
Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
       @Override
       public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
          Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("User-Agent", "Retrofit-Sample-App").build();
          return chain.proceed(newRequest);
       }
};

// Add the interceptor to OkHttpClient
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.interceptors().add(interceptor);
OkHttpClient client = builder.build();

// Set the custom client when building adapter
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
       .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
       .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
       .client(client)
       .build();
```

Reference: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Comment: it is true, it's very bad that retrofit not don't show headers