# How can i Send TOKEN in header request with Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I should send **Token** in **Header** to server, for android requests I use `Retrofit`.
I use code for Get header token and I can see token :

```
 InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
        Call<LoginResponse> call = api.getLoginResponse(loginDatum);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
                String token = response.headers().get("Token");
                if (token != null) {
                    Log.e("tokenTAG", "Token : " + token);
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, loginResponse.getStatusMessage() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                loadProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loginBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                loadProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loginBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
                    }
```

But I should Post this token in header to server, for POST data to server I use this code :

```
@POST("usersInfo/Authenticate")
Call<LoginResponse> getLoginResponse(@Body LoginDatum loginDatum);
```

How can I send token **(**`String token = response.headers().get("Token")`**)** to server this above POST code?

Please help me, i'm amateur.

Comment: See this Link.Hope it helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884967/how-to-dynamically-set-headers-in-retrofit-android

Answer (score 8):

Try this code :

```
private String sendToken;
```

replace this code with you code :

```
    InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
    Call<LoginResponse> call = api.getLoginResponse(sendToken, loginDatum);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
            String token = response.headers().get("Token");
            if (token != null) {
                Log.e("tokenTAG", "Token : " + token);
                sendToken = token;
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, loginResponse.getStatusMessage() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            loadProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loginBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            loadProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loginBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

and replace this code :

```
@POST("usersInfo/Authenticate")
Call<LoginResponse> getLoginResponse(@Header("Token") String token, @Body LoginDatum loginDatum);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [@Header](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Header.html) annotation. For your case, it would be like this.

```
  @POST("usersInfo/Authenticate")
  Call<LoginResponse> getLoginResponse(
      @Header("Token") String token,
      @Body LoginDatum loginDatum
  );
```