# Retrofit2/OKHttp3: set custom per-request headers programatically

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, connection-timeout

How can I specify custom per-request read/write/connect timeouts with `Retrofit2`/`OKHttp3`? Something like

```
Response<Listings> response = 
    ApiProvider.getServer1().getListings().setTimeouts(10000).execute();
```

Currently timeouts are set to 30s which is fine, but in one specific case I am bound by 10s execution limit and I need to make sure I get web response before that.

Based on [this nice GitHub comment](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2561#issuecomment-345641958) I know I could set custom timeouts with @Header and parsing them in OKHttp Interceptor, but as said before, I need custom timeouts for just one specific API call in a specific context.

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29885004/1181261) (option *1) Using OkHttp 2.2+ use Interceptor*), but I can't see how I can tell to interceptor that I need custom timeouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set header dynamically, you can pass value of header as a parameter in your method using `@Header` annotation.

Example:

```
@GET("some/url")
Call<SomeClass> doSomething(@Header("CONNECT_TIMEOUT") String timeOut);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Now I can "catch" this header in Interceptor, set timeouts, and then remove it from headers to avoid confusing the web server.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)