# Adding dynamic header to POST request with body (Retrofit v2.4.0)

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using Retrofit v2.4.0 in my project. I need to get token using one API call and using this token in header of the POST request I should use another API call where I should add one header and two parameter to the body of the request. The following code is of the second API call (JavaRx is used):

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("auth/sendCode")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
Single<SendCodeResponse> sendCode(@Header("token") String token,
                                  @Field("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber,
                                  @Field("langCode") String langCode);
```

However, it is not working. When I log my request, it is showing that the request body is not correct. 
What is wrong with my code above?

Comment: remove "content-type" header

Comment: @Mehta didn't work. (however, "Content-Type" should be there)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically set headers in Retrofit (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884967/how-to-dynamically-set-headers-in-retrofit-android)

Comment: Agree "Content-Type" should be there but you have already defined @FormUrlEncoded (request params in form data) and then you are  defining "application/json"( request body in json format-raw data)

Comment: Also check if key name for your security token is "token" or something else.